# highlight parent window text when spell checking from child window

Tags: c#, spell-checking

I'm working on a simple spell checking app for a lecture that I'm giving. I've got the basic spell checking code working just fine using a child form and NHunspell - great lib, by the way.

However, I'd like for the parent textbox to show the highlighted text for reference, and while I'm setting the SelectedText properties accordingly, the text is not highlighted in the parent. Canceling the child window and the parent text is highlighted.

Anybody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `HideSelection` to `false` on the `TextBox`.  That will make the `TextBox` show the selection even when it does not have focus.